# Jboss RestEasy - How do i extract binary data from a multipart mime MultipartInput using multipart/mixed

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy, jboss7.x

I have a MultipartInput that has two parts

- Part1 - XML string
- Part2 - Binary data (an image)

Here is an example of how i extract the data from the parts

```
@POST
@Path("/mixedMime")
@Consumes("multipart/mixed")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String mixedMime(@Context ServletContext servletContext, MultipartInput input) throws Exception{


   int index = 0;
   String xmlText; 
   byte[] imageData;

   for (InputPart part : input.getParts()) {
      index++;

      if(index==1){
        //extract the xml test
        xmlText = part.getBodyAsString()
      }

      if(index==2){
        //extract the image data
        imageData = part.getBody(???<<<<< WHAT GOES HERE >>>>???);
      }

   }
}
```

How would i extract the image data (binary data) shown above? I am using Jboss 7.0.2. 
According to the documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.0.GA/userguide/html/Multipart.html , it is saying i need to specify a class? what class?

Thanks

### Edit

Sorry i forgot to include how i am sending the data to the REST service. Here is the relevant code from the client. 
Basically i add the xml file from the file system as the first part. An an image as the second part.

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/RestTest/rest/mixedmime");

    Scanner scanner = 
       new Scanner(new File("myXmlFile.xml")).useDelimiter("\\Z");
       String messageHeader = scanner.next();
       scanner.close();


    FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("dexter.jpg"));
    StringBody header = new StringBody(messageHeader.toString());

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("header", header);
    reqEntity.addPart("payload", bin);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: How is the image file being transferred? Do you have sample data we can look at? Usually, when transferring an image over a network, you send it as stream of bytes and on the receiving end you read in a stream of bytes.

Comment: @FloopyDisk - See the edit showing the details of how the payload is sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how you would process binary (stream) data out of a multipart request with RESTEasy:

First, define a class to map your multipart form too:

```
public class DataUploadForm implements Serializable {
   static final long serialVersionUID = IL;

   @FormParam("xml")
   private String xml;

   @FormParam("file")
   private InputStream fileStream;

   public FileUploadForm() {
       super();
   }

   // Getters and setters here
}
```

Then on your web service interface, declare a method that handles multipart content and maps it to your custom class:

```
@POST
@Path("/somepath")
@Consumes({ MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
public Response uploadData(@MultipartForm DataUploadForm uploadForm);
```

And in your web service implementation, process the incoming request:

```
@Override
public Response uploadData(DataUploadForm uploadForm) {

    System.out.printf("Incoming xml data: %s\n", uploadForm.getXML());
    System.out.printf("Incoming binary data: %s\n", uploadForm.getFileStream());

    // Processing the input stream. For example, by using Apache Commons IO
    final byte[] data ;
    try {
       data = IOUtils.toByteArray(uploadForm.getFileStream());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
       throw new WebApplicationException("Could not read uploaded binary data");
    }

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: I am not using HTML forms. Would this still work even if the data is not coming from an HTML request?

Comment: Yes. Infact this is ripped from a service endpoint I wrote that is ***never*** called via an HTML form.

Comment: Excellent. Im trying it now. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately i cnat use the @ MultipartForm parameter. The signature i am using needs to use Spring's ServletContext - It looks like public String mixedMime(@ Context ServletContext servletContext, MultipartInput input)